# Convert a nested list of dataframes with different length to one dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, nested

I want to convert a nested list of dataframes to a single dataframe.

The list has some char columns as well as dataframes. Some of the nested dataframes have empty cells. I tried all the solutions on similar topic but none of them are working on this case. My current solution was trying to use `tidyr::unnest` and `qdapTools::t(mtabulate(data))`.

My current failed working:

```
page2_1 <- unnest(page2, cols = c(results.extensions, results.releases))
page2_2 <- unnest(page2_1, cols = c(tag))
page2_3 <- page2_2 %>% unnest_wider(., tender.milestones)

Error: Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "id" at locations 10 and 30.
  * "title" at locations 31 and 62.
  * "description" at locations 32 and 63.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `unnest`, we can use `names_repair`.  The default option checks for duplicated column names with `"check_unique"`.  According to `?unnest`, the "unique" value would help here

> "unique": make sure names are unique and not empty,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
page2_2 %>% 
    unnest_wider(., tender.milestones, names_repair = 'unique')
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I think it's working well to break the small dataframes. I am wondering if there's a way to do it in a scale? I tried this. `page2_3 <- page2_2 %>% unnest_wider(., c(tender.milestones, tender.items), names_repair = 'unique')
Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 2 but must be size 1.`

Comment: @Lawrence without a small reproducible example, it is not clear about your case. thanks

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Any advice if I wish to put down two columns rather than one - `page2_3 <- page2_2 %>% unnest_wider(., c(tender.milestones, tender.items), names_repair = 'unique')`  and I get this `Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript. x Subscript var` has size 2 but must be size 1`

Comment: @Lawrence can you please update your post with the `dput` of the data (small data) so that I can get the structure of your dataset

Comment: the `dput` is so nested I just have no idea how to make it smaller. But I have a rds object file sharing online https://filebin.net/5bmqan6suclb3th3

Comment: I am bit hesitant to download from external sites as it can be problematic

Comment: totally understandable. Is there a way to capture the dput if the output is slightly larger?

Comment: @Lawrence if you have a github account, you can get the dput and post it on your site

Comment: YES, how come I didn't think about that way! Thanks.

Comment: this is the gist https://gist.github.com/dataning/939192acd9d91d1397d5c3d58e19f9ea and it can take one minute to load back to R console. My intention is to find a better way to unnest this list.